# Why does liquid oxygen gets suspended between magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, liquid-state

I watched a video in which liquid oxygen when passed through the poles of the magnet gets suspended or rather sticks to it. It says it is due to diamagnetic nature of oxygen but in this way I think liquid nitrogen should repel from it as it is paramagnetic. But it went through without showing specific repulsion.  Why is this so

Comment: Link to video ?

Comment: https://youtu.be/KcGEev8qulA

Comment: It would be better to edit the post to include the link, not just to add it in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because of the diamagnetic nature and it would be wrong to say that diamagnetic and paramagnetic are just opposite.  They have different properties .

---

In case of paramagnetic material the material is weakly attracted in the field as the orientation of the atoms inside it arranges itself in the same direction  of the field , so nitrogen would be feebly attracted,  I see no point of it being repelled

Answer (score 1):

The O$_2$ molecule has a permanent magnetic moment. Liquid oxygen consists of such molecules hence is attracted to magnets.